# focus on UITextField

Tags: xcode, focus, uitextfield

I am doing a login page, whereby if the user press the login button without filling up the username/password, an alertview will pop up. How do I focus on the textfield and bring up the keyboard accordingly after the user dismiss the alertview?

What is the method to call to set focus on a particular UITextField? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your UIAlertView's delegate is your view controller (self), and in the implementation of the UIAlertView delegate method `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`, call `[usernameTextField becomeFirstResponder]`. Easy! (Make sure your view controller class adopts the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol.)

Comment: Thanks, managed to get it working for if the user forgets to fill up the username TextField. But as I also have an alertview when the user forgets to fill in the password. How do I make it becomefirstresponder when it's own alerview is dismissed. Am really new at this, haha.

Comment: You have to get clever. :-) Presumably your message in each case will be the same or similar, e.g. "Please enter a username." or "Please enter a password.". In the delegate method, you can determine which message was shown by examining alertView.message, e.g. `if ([alertView.message hasSuffix:@"username."]) { [username becomeFirstResponder]; } else { [password becomeFirstResponder]; }`

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Couldn't find the necessary methods available to call.

Answer (score 1):

```
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a code `[mytextField becomeFirstResponder];` in your `– alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method.

Comment: OP is looking for exactly the opposite thing.

Comment: @taskinoor: Yes, it is mine misprint. Of course the correct method name is becomeFirstResponder. Thanks for correction!